# Python (Django): environment variables, visibility

Tags: python, django, environment-variables

I've been trying to manage DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable the right way. To convenience, that is. This way (settings.py)

```
os.environ.setdefault("DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE", "tango_with_django_project.settings")
```

it works apparently fine:

```
In [14]: os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']
Out[14]: 'tango_with_django_project.settings'
```

Moreover, I got rid of the errors which made me address the issue. The only thing which keeps on bothering me is the difference in outputs: while **os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE']** or **os.environ.values** show the presence of the variable, **$ env** (Linux) does not. Though the respective lists of the environment variables are very similar indeed. Why not identical?

I understand that everything is just as it should be, but I can't find any indication that an environment variable can be less than global or per user. What am I missing?

Comment: environment variables are _per process_, and inherited from the parent process.  setting an environment variable in some python script will not have any impact on your shell, unless a shell is spawned by that python script.

Comment: Thanks! There's an avenue of further research.

Comment: Note, there's absolutely no point setting this var inside settings.py. The point is to let the system find the settings: by the time it gets inside that file, it must by definition already have found it.

Comment: So what would be the right way to manage it without affecting other Django projects? Ideally without paying attention more than once.

Comment: The normal way is to set it inside wsgi.py.

Comment: I has always been there, as it turned out :) . One should start server first, import settings later.

Comment: Is there any good explanation how Django *runs*? As a Python program. Under the hood, pointing out the relevant pieces of code. Activity diagrams leave you just as ignorant as before. I tried searching for something like "Django Execution for Dummies" more than once, but no luck. Can't think of the right keyword, probably.

Comment: more than django, you would need to understand more about your environment. For instance, are you deploying it on Apache, or are you just hosting your app with the dev server for testing? Are you using a virtual environment (which i highly recommend) or are you using the global python interpreter?

Comment: if you want to have it into shell and python the simplest way to define the vars is to define them into the shell - export VARA=A this will be present into $ env as well os.environ (python)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The dictionary `os.environ` contains the environment variables that the python process was spawned with, from the shell it was spawned in.

The piece of code `os.environ.setdefault('foo', 'bar')` tells this dictionary to provide the value 'bar' when looking up the ke 'foo'. This has nothing to do with the environment variables that the python process was started with, as creation of the `os.environ` dictionary is a one-way trip. The `os.environ` is not some kind of "reference" to a dictionary of the environment variables of your process, it's a copy of that. As such, modifying it has no effect in the shell.

There might be ways to hack the environment variables of the current process from python, but `os.environ` is simply a snapshot of the environment variables the process was started with. And as @Daniel Roseman correctly pointed out, if you start a console from inside the python process, the `os.environ` values will be again copied to the new shell. Modifying any variables from that shell will in turn have no effect on the `os.environ` of the python process that spawned the shell.

Another thing to consider is that whenever you want to start a django in a python interpreter, you need to have the `DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE` available ultimatelly to the django code. That can be accomplished either by starting the python interpreter in a console where that variable is set, by doing the `os.environ.setdefault` hack-ish thing, or just properly setting a key in that dict `os.environ['DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE'] = 'whatever'`.

Again as @Daniel Roseman has pointed out - you should be carefull when to do this. The script `manage.py` is only called from the console, but would not be called by the apache (or other) server you'd be serving your site from. The file `wsgi.py` however is extremely important for any web server, and setting your environemt variable there is fair enough (meaning it will work).

What I'm doing however is this: have a virtual environment that the server will be running in, and in that virtual environemt, always have the DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE variable set when the environment is activated, and unset it once you deactivate the environment. Check out virtualenv and virtualenvwrapper system packages (if you're using some kind of linux, those will be available for you)

Comment: Thanks, **vlad-ardelean**! A hint about how Django actually runs, why it sees any source change instantly, etc. is still welcome. I'm sure there's a good description, but I haven't yet found any.

Comment: @AlexeyOrlov here's the source code for the django command `runserver`. Perhaps it would be nice to have a look in there if you'd like to see what's going on. https://github.com/django/django/blob/stable/1.6.x/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py  i linked to the 1.6 version, so mind that. Anyway, the way django autoreloads seems to have something to do with some unix signaling as far as i could tell. didn't look much though. have fun!

Comment: Thank you very much, **vlad-ardelean**!